# Showing image from top to bottom using css animation only

Tags: css, animation

I want the image to be hidden by default, and when the website start loading / refresh it showing from it's top to it's bottom smoothly (only the image).
I've used animation keyframes with the opacity but it show the full image smoothly, not part by part from top to bottom.
Is there a way for it?
If it can't be done with the images, I think I can put it as an empty background if there is a way to do it for the text inside it like it's written from top to bottom.
Any way could help

Note: I don't want the image to move from top to bottom, I want it in it's place to appear slowly from it's top part to it's bottom part.

I've used animation keyframes with opacity only, and that's not what I want, hope you can help me.
here is the used css code

```
.myimg {
animation: transitionIn 4s;
}

@keyframes transitionIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 100%;
    // transform: rotateX(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `clip-path`?

```css
.myImg {
  animation: transitionIn 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes transitionIn {
  from {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
  }
  to {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/baconmockup/img/bm-home-140.jpg" alt="" class="myImg">
```